# Installing Laravel just gives me a blank page

Tags: apache, laravel

I'm trying to install Laravel locally on my computer by following the instructions given on their website. I used the command `laravel new blog` in my `/var/www` folder, but when I try to access `localhost/blog/public`, I get nothing but a blank page. I've tried using a different .htaccess file and changing the permissions of storage to 777, but nothing has worked.

Answer (score 0):

Have your webserver serve the public folder for your document root.  If you serve this folder then you would just access http://localhost

If you are creating multiple projects (or working with different frameworks) your better off creating virtual hosts for all your projects.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to reach your site through:
http://localhost/blog

If this doesn't solve your problem I would advice setting up your server the Laravel recommended way using [Homestead](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/homestead). Also check out some free Laracast-episodes to help you getting started on homestead.